# MySql inner join COUNT>0

Tags: mysql, sorting, count, inner-join

How can i select all the rows with a count>0 ?

"where hits>0" does not work.

```
SELECT b . * , COUNT( a.abfrage_id ) AS  `hits` 
FROM abfragen_ergebnisse a
RIGHT JOIN suchen b ON a.abfrage_id = b.id
WHERE b.id <140
GROUP BY b.id
ORDER BY  `hits` DESC , b.`id` ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`HAVING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html):

```sql
SELECT b . * , COUNT( a.abfrage_id ) AS  `hits`
FROM abfragen_ergebnisse a
  RIGHT JOIN suchen b ON a.abfrage_id = b.id
WHERE b.id <140
GROUP BY b.id
HAVING `hits` > 0
ORDER BY  `hits` DESC , b.`id` ASC
```